# How to implement factorial function in RISC-V

Tags: factorial, riscv

```
    C-code  :

int factorial(int n) 
{
if (n<1) return 1;
 else return n * factorial (n-1);
}
```

I've tried to implement it but haven't managed to do a lot. So here is my try:

```
     goto:

 factorial:
 int factorial(int n) {
 if (n<1) goto Lthen;

 Lelse:
 tmp=factorial(n-1);
 return n*tmp;
 goto Lend;

 Lthen: return 1;
 Lend;
 }



 RISC V:
.factorial
 addi sp, sp,  -16
 sw ra, (sp)
 sw s0, 4(sp) //n
 sw s1, 8(sp) //tmp
 mv s0, a0               //a--->s0
 addi t1, zero,1 
 blt s0, t1, Lthen

   .Lelse
   mv t0, s0          // copy of n to t0
   addi s0, s0, -1   // n-1
   mv a0, s0;        // n-1--->a0
   jal factorial // factorial(a0)
   mv s1, a0         // s1=factorial(a0) //tmp
   mul a0,t0,s1        //  n*tmp ----> a0 
   ret
   j LEND



Lthen: li a0,1
ret
LEND jr ra, 0
```

Can somebody tell me is that okay, because I don't know how to test it.
And I am not sure about for example return 1 /or any other value/expression, can we just put it in a0 and say ret..

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Use [RARS](https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars) -- the RISC V counterpart to MIPS MARS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$s0` for the preserved value, instead of `$t0`.

You should be subtracting one from $a0 after copying from `$s0` before the recursive call.

The multiply then would go between the `$a0` return value and the `$s0` preserved value.

The reason `$s0` will work but `$t0` won't (to preserve the original `$a0` input), is that you are making the (correct) effort to save the `s` registers.

However, you are not restoring the saved values in function epilogue, nor cutting back the stack, nor reloading `$ra`...

Comment: Thank you, now with all those things in mind I think I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive factorial function in RISC-V from my [RV32I assembly programmer's quick reference](https://github.com/dylanmc/CS2-RISC-V/raw/master/Extra%20stuff/RISC-V%20quick%20ref%20card.pdf): (comments welcome!)

```
.text  # recursive implementation of factorial
.globl __start
fact:       # arg: n in a0, returns n! in a1
    addi  sp, sp, -8    # reserve our stack area
    sw ra, 0(sp)    # save the return address
    li t0, 2
    blt a0, t0, ret_one # 0! and 1! == 1
    sw a0, 4(sp)    # save our n
    addi a0, a0, -1
    jal fact        # call fact (n-1)
                    # a1 <- fact(n-1)
    lw t0, 4(sp)    # t0 <- n
    mul a1, t0, a1  # a1 <- n * fact(n-1)
    j done
ret_one:
    li a1, 1
done:
    lw ra, 0(sp)    # restore return address from stack
    addi sp, sp, 8  # free our stack frame
    jr ra           # and return

__start:
    li a0, 5        # compute 5!
    jal fact
    li a0, 1        # print it
    ecall
    li a0, 17
    ecall       # and exit
```

To test it, my favorite lightweight RISC-V simulators are [Venus](https://www.kvakil.me/venus/) and [Jupiter](https://docs.riscvsim.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple code:

```
.data

ask1: .string "Please enter a number to compute its factorial value:   "
msg: .string "The result is:   \n"

.text

la a0, ask1
li a7, 4
ecall

li a7, 5
ecall

jal ra, Factorial
j print

Factorial:

beqz a0, return
addi sp, sp, -8
sw ra, 4(sp)
sw a0, 0(sp)
addi a0, a0, -1
jal ra, Factorial
lw a1, 0(sp)
addi sp, sp, 4
mul a0, a1, a0
lw ra, 0(sp) 
addi sp, sp, 4
jr ra

return:
addi a0, x0, 1
jr ra


print:
add s0, x0, a0

la a0, msg
li a7, 4
ecall

add a0, x0, s0
addi a7, x0, 1
ecall
```